# Resigning within Probationary Period

Tags: resignation, probation

I am an experienced hire, into my 4th year of work, working in an Asian country. Currently, I am into my 3rd month with my Company A which has a probationary period of 3 months and a notice period of 2 weeks.

Before I entered Company A, I have also applied for another job in Company B which is in a totally different industry, one that really interests me. It is really rare and difficult for someone with my background to get into that industry.

In my 1st month with my Company A, I went for 2 interviews with Company B. The final interview was 5 weeks back and I initially thought that it was a goner. However, yesterday, Company B called me to offer me the job.

I am definitely going for Company B. I strongly believe and have confidence that that is in line with my career goals (learning things that I am interested in) and the prospects are much better in that industry, although there is an initial paycut.  But the complication is that:
1) My role with Company A is a project role and the project is commencing this coming Monday (a 2-week workshop).
2) There is one other person who is working on this project "part-time". But we are definitely under-staffed.

I would like to seek your advice on how I should bring across my case to my boss as I seek to resign from Company A. How should I bring my point across? My real concern is my boss (F). How can I minimize burning the bridges? Should I suggest to do a short notice to minimize the awkwardness?

I also cannot help but feel bad and guilty. Especially towards my boss and my friend who referred me into Company A. Any advice on this as well?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 6):

Frankly, you *are* going to burn bridges here. When interviewing with company A, you probably said something like "I'm really interested in company A and the wider industry they're in". You're about to turn round and admit that wasn't the truth, you really wanted work in a different industry, and what's more you **had already already applied for a different job** - you can't even spin this as "I've had a change of heart" as your intention always to quit company A as soon as you find a job in company B's industry.

You can pretty much expect never to have good relations with company A again after this, and quite possibly your reputation with company A's industry is shot as well. However, if company B and their industry are truly what you want, then that's possibly a price that's worth paying - only you can make that decision.

Answer (score 5):

You are on prob. This means they can dismiss you any time and presumably, you can quit any time. Best to leave ASAP because the sooner you leave, the less they have to invest with you. Give them the usual notice - two weeks? - that's probably enough time for them to reconfigure their workflow and start looking for a replacement for you. If not, it's their problem how to go forward without you. Not yours.

You're going to piss off your boss by leaving - that goes without saying. Best not to worry about things you cannot change. You are better off leaving and piss off your boss, than pissing off your boss by telling your boss that you are leaving, then change your mind and stay, continuing to work for your boss who is now seriously pissed at you.

If you are going to amputate, do it quick and neat. Don't linger and don't play with the hacksaw.

Answer (score 4):

While Philip's point is good, I think there is a better way to do this.

You are in a probationary period - which is a time for you and the employer to decide whether or not you like each other.

Tell them you have realised you are not a good fit for the company (or vice versa) and that you have found something that is better suited to you. You don't need to go into detail.

Leaving during the probationary period is often preferable to staying longer and having the company invest more in you and then leaving.